# Apps script cant return boolean value from server by google.script.run

Tags: google-apps-script

I have brain storm about this.

In Apps Script and Spreadsheet I have function

```
    function searchLogins(UserInfo){
    
    let sheetSRCHLGN = sprSRCH.getSheetByName("LOGINS");
    let findingRLGN = sheetSRCHLGN.getRange("A:A").getValues();
    let valToFind = UserInfo.zLOGIN;
   
    for (let i = 0; i < findingRLGN.length; i++){
      if(findingRLGN[i].indexOf(valToFind)!==-1){
        return true;
      }
    };
    return false;
    
}
```

In HTML-form I have this:

```
var UserInfo = {};
    UserInfo.zLOGIN = document.getElementById("LOGIN").value;
    UserInfo.zSSCC = document.getElementById("SSCC").value;
    UserInfo.zPLACE = document.getElementById("PLACE").value;


 var findLogin = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).searchLogins(UserInfo);
          if (!findLogin){
            allValid = false;
          };
```

.....

```
function onSuccess(findLogin) {
if (!findLogin) {
    M.toast({
        html: "LOGIN IS NOT EXISTS"
    });
}
```

I need to return data from server in boolean values (true/false) but alwais I get "undefined".
I know I must do it by withSuccessHandler, but it doesnt help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#withsuccesshandlerfunction)

- Sets a callback function to run if the server-side function returns successfully. The **server's return value is passed to the function as the first argument**, and the user object (if any) is passed as a second argument.
- Returns a `google.script.run`
- You can refer to the `Index.html` tab from the reference link provided for an additional sample code.

The value you are expecting is passed to your assigned callback function which is `onSuccess(findLogin)`. If you want to check the value returned by `searchLogins(UserInfo)`, you can display the value of `findLogin` in `onSuccess(findLogin)` function

**Sample HTML:**

```
var UserInfo = {};
UserInfo.zLOGIN = document.getElementById("LOGIN").value;
UserInfo.zSSCC = document.getElementById("SSCC").value;
UserInfo.zPLACE = document.getElementById("PLACE").value;

google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).searchLogins(UserInfo);


.....

function onSuccess(findLogin) {
  alert(findLogin);
  if (!findLogin) {
    M.toast({
      html: "LOGIN DOES NOT EXIST"
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm junior at this. Your help is perfect! It works!)))

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, If we answered your question, please click the accept button.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: I can't find anywhere this button((

Comment: Hi @DmitriyRudakov thank you for the update. You can accept an answer by click the "check mark" button underneath the vote buttons. [How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)